# Can Ricci flow be used to prove Poincaré’s conjecture for $n=2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, ricci-flow

This question is concerning the conjecture described in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture) Wikipedia article. The conjecture has been proved for dimension two ($n = 2$). For $n=3$, conjecture is proved using Ricci flow. My question is, can Ricci flow be used to solve the conjecture for any $n$ or for $n=2$?  Can Ricci flow defined for any $n$?

Comment: This question seems like it might be more suitable for mathoverflow, no? Seems like it's closer to a research question.

Comment: @ThePointer really? I assumed it would be straight forward, yes ? But I don't know how.

Comment: I'm asking you – you know better than I do. If you think it's more appropriate here (if this isn't closer to a research question), then feel free to leave it.

Comment: @ThePointer, I am not sure. If so, somone may move it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that simply-connected closed surfaces $S$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^2$ is well-known, indeed the [uniformization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) states that any metric on $S$ is conformal to the standard metric on $\mathbb S^2$.

There is, indeed, a proof of this fact using the Ricci flow by Hamilton and Chow. You may read [this survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4669.pdf), in particular section 3 for more information.

Let me point out that Ricci flow in dimension $n\ge 4$ is much more difficult, in dimension 2, the only curvature is the Gauss curvature (a scalar), while in dimension 3, the Ricci curvature determine the whole Riemann curvature tensor $R$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2194463/629362)). In dimension $n\ge 4$, it is much harder to control the whole $R$ along the Ricci flow (which is defined using only the Ricci curvature).

Comment: How about 1 D? Would you please show some article related to 1D?

Comment: What's the point of proving that in 1d? All metrics in 1d have zero curvature, so ricci flow is trivial; and there is no simply connected 1d manifold @creator